# Making a looping drawSVG animation smoother

Tags: svg, gsap

I'm a novice with GSAP and am experimenting with the plugin. I want to create an effect where a rectangles border is drawn by a small path in a continuous loop. I've mostly achieved this, but the end of the animation is pretty choppy when it resets.

[Here's a link](https://codepen.io/strigiforme/pen/zLbYWm) to the codepen I'm working on.

**How can I avoid that abrupt ending to the animation?**

- I've tried setting the animation to `drawSVG: "100% 115%"` and that didn't work.
- I haven't tried changing the easing yet as I don't think that would fix it.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this tutorial is exactly what you're trying to achieve [Codepen](https://codepen.io/PointC/post/seamless-loop-svg-stroke-animations)

```
code required for codepen link
```

I forked your pen so you can see it in action 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/alaricweb/pen/fea3042207fc6ee0f2a9c07e6a99259c/)

Hope this is what you where looking for

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer didn't sit right with me as I felt like something more elegant could be done. I found a simple solution where GSAP isn't used, but CSS animations are.

The result is a smooth animation using only one element.

GSAP manipulates CSS animations anyway so this is a simplification of the original problem.

https://codepen.io/strigiforme/pen/zLbYWm

```
<svg viewbox = "0 0 200 200">
 <rect id = "rect" x = "85" y = "20" width="30" height="30" stroke = "red" stroke-width = "1.5" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="30 90" stroke-dashoffset = "240"></rect>
```

```
body {
  background-color: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
} 

#rect{
  animation: draw 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes draw{
 14%{
   stroke: orange;
 }
 28%{
   stroke: yellow;
 }
 42%{
   stroke: green;
 }
 56%{
   stroke: blue;
 }
 70%{
   stroke: indigo;
 }
 84%{
   stroke: violet;
 }
 98%{
   stroke: red;
 }
 to{
   stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```